# Access native memory transparently from .NET assembly

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, c++-cli

I am in the process of evaluating the possibilities to implement a plugin infrastructure for a native application that allows extensions to be written in managed code. The plugins will operate on large(-ish) floating point buffers allocated on the native heap which are fairly expensive in terms of memory footprint to copy. As a consequence a plugin should be able to operate on the native memory directly.

As far as I understand it is possible to access native memory from managed code by using [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t2yzs44b.aspx) (to my understanding this is the only provision in the .NET framework to do so). To ease development of plugins I would rather not expose this artifact and provide a proxy mechanism instead so that buffers can be accessed like managed collections.

There are no restrictions as to the implementation (a C++/CLI interop layer is fine, for example) or a specific .NET runtime version. The buffers can be assumed to be of fixed size as well; the plugin will modify the contents only.

Is it possible to implement an infrastructure that meets the requirements layed out above and if so, what options exist?

Comment: Write a managed class that provides an interface suitable foor manipulation of said buffer? Said class would use pointers and stuff in its guts, but only expose safe managed bits.

Comment: you can provide COM visible and make COM objects dealing with unmanaged code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement an infrastructure that meets the requirements layed out above and if so, what options exist?

You won't be able to treat the native data as a managed array directly, but you can expose a layer via C++/CLI that allows direct, indexable access to that memory.

For example, suppose you have a buffer comprised of a few million double precision floating point values.  You can easily make a C++/CLI `ref class` that exposes a window onto that buffer via an indexer, or even better, as an `IList<T>`.

This would potentially allow it to be used from C# as if it were a normal `IList<T>`, without copying the data, as the wrapper class only needs the buffer memory locations stored.

Comment: That's essentially what I was after, being able to read from and write to native memory without forwarding this feature as a liability. This also sounds like there are no additional managed-unmanaged transitions involved once the C++/CLI wrapper is through constructing an `IList<T>` object (I could be wrong). Now that would be perfect!

Comment: @IInspectable C++/CLI will, effectively, have to do some managed/unmanaged transitions.  If you do this, you'll find there's a (very slight) overhead when accessing via a purely managed route, but this is usually dramatically better than the cost of copying the memory, even in chunks.

Comment: @IInspectable I do this in my current project quite a bit, as it's really the only way to handle very large data in a mixed mode assembly cleanly.